# Shopware 6 - docker:start fails with non-zero code: 2

Tags: docker, shopware

First I pull this repo: https://github.com/shopware/development
Then I want to start a demo shop with command `./psh.phar docker:start` in the repo directory.
Then this error appears, and the containers are not biult:

```sh
Building app_mysql  ... done
    Successfully tagged shopware-test_app_mysql:latest
 ---> Running in e0e02269e83d
    Listen 8000
    Warning: apt-key output should not be parsed (stdout is not a terminal)
    gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
    
    ERROR: for app_server  (<Service: app_server>, 'The command \'/bin/sh -c sed -ri -e \'s!VirtualHost \\*:80!VirtualHost \\*:8000!g\' /opt/docker/etc/httpd/vhost.conf     && echo "Listen 8000" | tee -a /etc/apache2/ports.conf         && curl -sL https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -     && sh -c \'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list\'         && curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | apt-key add -     && sh -c \'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch stable" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list\'         && mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man1     && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash         && mkdir -p ${NPM_CONFIG_CACHE}     && apt-install default-mysql-client nodejs google-chrome-stable libicu-dev graphviz vim gnupg2 docker-ce=5:18.09.7~3-0~debian-stretch libgtk2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libgbm-dev libnotify-dev libgconf-2-4 libnss3 libxss1 libasound2 libxtst6 xauth xvfb         && npm install -g npm@^6.14.11     && npm i forever -g     && chown -R ${USER_ID}:${GROUP_ID} ${NPM_CONFIG_CACHE}         && ln -s /app/psh.phar /bin/psh         && pecl install pcov     && docker-php-ext-enable pcov\' returned a non-zero code: 2')
    Service 'app_server' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c sed -ri -e 's!VirtualHost \*:80!VirtualHost \*:8000!g' /opt/docker/etc/httpd/vhost.conf     && echo "Listen 8000" | tee -a /etc/apache2/ports.conf         && curl -sL https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -     && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'         && curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | apt-key add -     && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch stable" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list'         && mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man1     && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash         && mkdir -p ${NPM_CONFIG_CACHE}     && apt-install default-mysql-client nodejs google-chrome-stable libicu-dev graphviz vim gnupg2 docker-ce=5:18.09.7~3-0~debian-stretch libgtk2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libgbm-dev libnotify-dev libgconf-2-4 libnss3 libxss1 libasound2 libxtst6 xauth xvfb         && npm install -g npm@^6.14.11     && npm i forever -g     && chown -R ${USER_ID}:${GROUP_ID} ${NPM_CONFIG_CACHE}         && ln -s /app/psh.phar /bin/psh         && pecl install pcov     && docker-php-ext-enable pcov' returned a non-zero code: 2
    
Execution aborted, a subcommand failed!
```

The same happens when I run `docker-compose up`.
What is the problem there?

I run Xubuntu 18.04. This used to work fine a few weeks ago. What could have happened?

I also opened an issue on Github: https://github.com/shopware/development/issues/161

Comment: Please share more details. What have you tried to resolve the problem? If this is a vanilla checkout from that repository, why not open a bug ticket in their issue tracker?

Comment: Yes it is a vanilla checkout. I also completely deleted my local docker cache to make sure there wasn't anything messed up. I think it is a problem on my machine and not in the repo because when I googled the error, on gitter someone had the same problem in 2020, but got no answer (see here: https://gitter.im/shopware/platform?at=5e29444d6b64bc54d1373614 )

Comment: However you are right, I'll open an issue over there

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look into the error, here:

> curl -sL https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub |
> apt-key add -

download the key and try to use it, but gives you this error:

```
Warning: apt-key output should not be parsed (stdout is not a terminal)
```

You should check if in your environment docker is able to download that key and use it

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Can you elaborate how I can check this and how I can solve this? I don't even know why out of the sudden my local docker instance should not be able to do that, because it did a few weeks ago and I didn't update it since then (Docker version 20.10.6, build 370c289).

Comment: You should look into the curl command, check if on your local machine you can do it without problem, then try to run the docker container in interactive way and do the same

Comment: Works locally. Since the Shopware container doesn't get built I checked in a different container, worked there

Answer (score 1):

I kind of solved this by updating Xubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04. The apt-key output error remains, but otherwise the containers get built.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue on ubuntu 22 when docker-compose was not installed, so just run:

```
sudo apt install docker-compose
```